# grandstream UCM6104 VOIP PBX phone

Tags: voip

I am using **grandstream UCM6104**.

- The system displays list of call start time, call duration, end time.
- I want to display the list of number of incoming call and display on
  the website which is accessed using the IP address..

How can I do this??

Which api should I use?

Answer (score 0):

You need to work with device's web services which you can access with the local IP address of the grandstream.

Reference:
http://www.grandstream.com/sites/default/files/Resources/GXV_GMI_Web_Service_Guide.pdf

Example.

You can use the following command to do curl from the terminal

## To login and get cookies saved of HTTP response

```
curl -H "Content-Type: text/xml" -D "cookies.txt" "http://192.168.123.127/manager?action=login&username=admin&secret=admin&format=json&jsoncallback=?"
```

- Here, I am using default username(admin) and password(admin) in above command; change accordingly
- Here, 192.168.123.127 is the IP address of the grandstream phone

## To see phone SIP's information

```
curl -H "Content-Type: text/xml" --cookie "cookies.txt" "http://192.168.123.127/manager?action=status&format=json&jsoncallback=?"
```